How to include code coverage for nunit unit test project also in the coverlet and covertura configin azure pipeline with yml
I have 3 projects in my solution including the test project. I get only 2 project in code coverage result in the azure pipeline which excludes the test project. I want to include the test project also in the code coverage.I am trying to get the code coverage in the azure pipeline for the solution which should include the code coverage for my nunit test project also. However it's not working below is my yml change.
# Run tests with Coverlet code coverage and include the test project in coverage results
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Run Tests'
  inputs:
    command: 'test'
    projects: '**/Warsy.Fulto.Test.csproj'
    arguments: |
      --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
      --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage"
      /p:Include="[Warsy.Fulto.Test]*"
      --verbosity detailed

# Publish code coverage results
- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@2
  displayName: 'Publish CodeCoverage'
  inputs:
    codeCoverageTool: 'Cobertura'
    summaryFileLocation: '$(Agent.TempDirectory)/**/coverage.cobertura.xml'


What do you mean exactly by "it's not working"? Is there any error? Check the code sample in
Collect code coverage metrics with Coverlet.

it means it is not covering my test project in the resultant

Hi @b_J, As far as I tested, the | indicator would have the dotnet test command broken. You may double check the actual command in blue from the pipeline logs and have a test with my sample below.

As far as I tested, the | indicator for the arguments property of the DotNetCoreCLI@2 task would have the dotnet test command broken.

You may try with a single-line argument or use the multiline string indicator > instead of | in the arguments property of the DotNetCoreCLI@2 task as in my sample below.
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  sytem.debug: true
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Build solution'
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '$(solution)'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Run Tests'
  inputs:
    command: 'test'
    projects: '**/AzureWebAppDotNetCore8Tests.csproj'
    arguments: >
      --no-build
      --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
      --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage"
      /p:Include="[AzureWebAppDotNetCore8.Tests]*"
      --verbosity detailed
  continueOnError: true
- powershell: tree $(Agent.BuildDirectory) /f /a
  displayName: Check test and coverage results

# Publish code coverage results
- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@2
  displayName: 'Publish CodeCoverage'
  inputs:
    codeCoverageTool: 'Cobertura'
    summaryFileLocation: '$(Agent.TempDirectory)/**/coverage.cobertura.xml'




This is not adding classes present in the test project to be in the code coverage. Here you can see the error that only project can be taken at a time

Can you share some of your pipeline logs that show the issue or error in your original post or some screenshots to help understand your expectation?

I have 3 projects in my solution includsing the test project. I get only 2 project in code coverage result in the azure pipeline which exclues the test project. I want to include the test project also in the code coverage.

What if you ran the same dotnet test command locally. Does generate the same code coverage report?

locally also not working. only 2 projects it is covering

Yes, you may share this information in your original post and seek assistance from the experts that are more familiar with dotnet test.
